Functorial relationships between Hopf algebras and rough paths
In rough paths theory, the signature of a path $x: [0, T] \to \mathbb{R}^d$  is an element in the tensor algebra $T((\mathbb{R}^d))$. These signatures reside within the group-like elements and naturally inherit a Hopf algebra structure.
Separately, the Hopf algebra of rooted trees, as developed by Connes and Kreimer, is instrumental in understanding renormalization in quantum field theory, related to combinatorial structures through operations like grafting and pruning.
Rough Paths as Objects in a Category:
Consider the category $\mathbf{RoughPaths}$ where:

Objects are rough paths $\mathbf{X}$ defined on $[0, T]$ taking
values in a finite-dimensional vector space $V$.

Morphisms between rough paths are Lipschitz continuous maps that respect the rough path structure.


Alternatively, we can consider a more structured category where morphisms are lifted to transformations of signatures.
Signatures as Functors
Define a functor $S: \mathbf{RoughPaths} \to \mathbf{HopfAlg}$, where $\mathbf{HopfAlg}$ is the category of (graded) Hopf algebras over $\mathbb{R}$.

For each rough path $\mathbf{X}$, $S(\mathbf{X})$ is its signature,
an element in the completed tensor algebra $T((V))$, which is a Hopf
algebra with concatenation (multiplication) and deconcatenation
(comultiplication).
For a morphism $f: \mathbf{X} \to \mathbf{Y}$ in $\mathbf{RoughPaths}$, $S(f): S(\mathbf{X}) \to S(\mathbf{Y})$ is the
induced morphism in $\mathbf{HopfAlg}$.

This functorial perspective allows us to study rough paths via their signatures in a categorical setting.
The signature functor $S: \mathbf{RoughPaths} \to \mathbf{HopfAlg}$ maps rough paths to their signatures in the category of Hopf algebras.
Consider the inclusion functor $I: \mathbf{SmoothPaths} \hookrightarrow \mathbf{RoughPaths}$, where $\mathbf{SmoothPaths}$ is the category of smooth paths.
There may exist a left adjoint to $I$, representing a rough pathification process that associates to each rough path a "best approximation" by smooth paths.
Given this recall, my question is:
Can one explicitly construct a functor between the category of branched rough paths (where objects are enhanced paths $(x, \mathcal{X})$ satisfying Chen's identity and certain regularity conditions) and the category of Hopf algebras of rooted trees, such that this functor aligns the algebraic operations in the Hopf algebra with the combinatorial structures of rough paths?
More specifically:

How does this functor translate operations like the coproduct, antipode, and convolution in the Hopf algebra to corresponding operations on rough paths and their signatures?
In what way does this functorial relationship assist in solving differential equations driven by rough paths, particularly regarding the renormalization of stochastic differential equations with irregular signals?
Are there explicit examples or constructions that illustrate this functor, perhaps showing how a rough path's iterated integrals correspond to rooted trees in the Hopf algebra?

Understanding this connection could provide valuable insights into the algebraic underpinnings of rough paths and offer new tools for tackling complex stochastic systems.
